# Radio button checked not returning correct value.

Tags: android, android-layout

In my XML layout I have defined 3 radio buttons. The first button has been set to `checked="true"`

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick" 
            android:checked="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick" />
    </TableRow>
```

In the `MainActivity.Java` file  , I initialise the radio buttons.

```
rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
```

In the same file , I have defined a `onRadioButtonClick()` method

```
public void onRadioButtonClick(View v)
    {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

         switch(v.getId()) {
     case R.id.radioButton1:    
    if (checked){
        MyButton = "1P";
    }
    break;

case R.id.radioButton2:
    if (checked){
        MyButton = "2P";
    }
    break;

case R.id.radioButton3:
    if (checked){
        MyButton = "3P";
    }   
    break;
     }}
```

And finally on click of a standard button (not radio one) , I have defined the `onClick()` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("LogThis", "My Print >" +MyButton);   

}
```

The `MyButton` value prints as `null` when I click the standard button which activates the `onClick` method.This happens despite of `radioButton1` is selected when the app loads.

This behaviour disappears once I manually select any other radio button. Then `MyButton` shows the correct value.

Is there any alternative way to approach this issue ? Where am I going wrong? I am assuming this is because I have implemented the logic in  `onRadioButtonClick()` button . But I am not sure what alternative approach to take to resolve this issue.

PS: I can't user `RadioGroup` as the buttons needs aligned to different columns in a `TableLayout.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to set the default checked RadioButton in code when you load your view and set `MyButton` variable at the same time. Example:

```
rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

rb1.setChecked(true);
MyButton = "1P";
```

Comment: I like the suggestion simple yet effective :). I'd wait some more time to see if someone can explain if I went wrong programatically and/or in design , just to be able to improve my coding :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413725/view-getid-and-r-id-viewlabel-return-different-values) you need to compare the RadioButton objects (by calling their own `getId()`, rather than comparing `View.getId()` to `R.id.radioButtonX`

e.g.

```
rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

switch(v.getId()) {
  case   (rb1.getId()) //NOT R.id.radioButton1:    
    if (checked){
        MyButton = "1P";
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The whole thing is in `onRadioButtonClick` , will it work without click on any radio button ?

Comment: It will if you add a `default` case to your switch block.